# Movie with different stories about the Ten Commandments

Tags: identify-this-movie

I would like to ask if somebody knows a movie about the ten commandments in which each commandment connects to one story of different people and they all talk to a black guy about their problems and it turns out that he is God.

I remember that there was a story about a woman, who discovered she is seriously ill and she decided to freeze herself, and one different story about a senator who loved a woman, but they could not be together and she hides from him the fact she had a child with him.

It was a very beautiful movie and I would like to see it again but I cannot remember the name.

Comment: Any additional details that might help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Anything you remember might be helpful.

Comment: There was a Polish TV series called [The Decalogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decalogue_%28TV_series%29) consisting of ten hour-long episodes where each was inspired by one of the Ten Commandments.

Comment: There was a comedy called "The Ten" that follows that theme. On another note, there is a new series upcoming that will feature one segment filmed by a different director for each commandment. Each one will be aired on a different night for 10 nights. http://www.indiewire.com/article/television/ten-commandments-wgn-america-gus-van-sant-lee-daniels-jim-sheridan-wes-craven-michael-cera

Comment: Not sure about your God ID, as the only black actors I can find that have played the role are Morgan Freeman (Bruce Almighty) and Rex Ingram (Green Pastures, 1936)

Answer (score 5):

This might be ['I am' from 2010](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1497617/combined). It's about '10 people and their failure to follow the 10 commandments'. The titular character is God according to the film's official website, played by [an African-American](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tomas+Boykin&tbm=isch). Here's the trailer: